# How to filter text rows inside pre tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter out text inside `pre` tags. I know this is not conventional, and am not sure if this could even be done. My end goal is to only show lines that match the search. There is only one line in my example code that has a **z**. The goal is that if **z** is searched for, only the line matching **z** shows. Currently, when no matches are found, the entire section disappears.

Also, my example is for one div container, but in reality, there will be many more of the same containers. It would be nice if the filter could apply to all the div containers simultaneously. A solution using JS or jquery is preferred.

Here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, div, pre, h1, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // ul = document.getElementById("lsoutput");
    li = document.getElementsByClassName("context")

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[0].getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

<form autocomplete="off" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="filter">
</form>
<div class="container context">
    <pre>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
totam rem aperiam
eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit
sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est
qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet
consectetur
z
adipisci velit
sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam
quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam
nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur
vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </pre>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctrdu96y/)

Comment: Do you mean the entire line?

Comment: @Pavlo yes; if there is a match, i would like to show the entire line. But if no match, then the lines will be hidden.

Comment: Which solution do you prefer. Having two `<pre>` tags so we can just hide the original when input isn't empty or saving the entire text in JavaScript?

Comment: Hmm... the html is being generated by a script, so i think it will probably be easiest for me to integrate a JS or jquery solution vs two pre tags. Also, my example is for one div container, but in reality, there will be many more of the same containers. It would be nice if the filter could apply to all the div containers simultaniously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution I would use, no doubt there are many in the air (it is a reusable code):

```js
function myFunction(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var thisInput = $(this);
 var thisInputValue = $.trim(thisInput.val().toLowerCase());
 $(thisInput.data('filter')).each(function(j) {
  var toFilter = $(this);
  if (toFilter.find('span').length < 1) {
   /* Split lines using spans, but include ending new line char */
   var oldText = toFilter.text();
   var oldTextSplit = oldText.split('\n');
   var newText = '<span>' + oldTextSplit.join('\n</span><span>') + '\n</span>';
   toFilter.html(newText);
  };
  if (thisInputValue) {
   /* Filter (hide) rows which contain no filter */
   toFilter.find('span').each(function(i) {
    var thisRow = $(this);
    var thisRowText = thisRow.text().toLowerCase();
    if (thisRowText.indexOf(thisInputValue) < 0) {
     thisRow.addClass('invisible-row');
    } else {
     thisRow.removeClass('invisible-row');
    };
   });
  } else {
   /* Nothing to filter, show all rows */
   toFilter.find('span').removeClass('invisible-row');
  };
 });
};
$('[data-filter]').on('input', myFunction);
```

```css
.invisible-row {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form autocomplete="off" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
 <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="type to filter" data-filter=".filter-my-lines, .filter-me-also">
</form>
<pre class="filter-my-lines">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
totam rem aperiam
eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit
sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est
qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet
consectetur
z
adipisci velit
sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam
quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam
nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur
vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</pre>
<pre class="filter-me-also">1234
Other pre container
Also Z here!
</pre>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3e6byth/).

EDIT: Also works with multiple targets.

Comment: This works great! Will this also work with multiple div containers while filter simultaneously?

Comment: I edited the code, hope that is what you wanted to see.

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>

        var pres = undefined;
        var preLines = undefined; //Is set before user can click on input

        //Wait til page is rendered
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

            pres = document.getElementByTagName('pre');
            var preToArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(pres); //or
            // var preToArray = Array.from(pres); //This is an ES6 function

            //create a list of pre's who have a list of lines
            preLines = preToArray.reduce(function(sum, pre){
                sum.push(pre.innerHTML.split('/n'));
                return sum; 
            },[]);
        });

        function textFilter(element) {
            var inputValue = element.value.toUpperCase();
            var contextClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('context');

            for (var i = 0; i < contextClasses.length; i++) {
                //Not really sure what to do with contextClasses
                var currentPre = pres[i];
                var preLine = preLines[i];
                var renderedLine = preLine.filter(
                    function(element){
                        return element.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1;
                    });
                if(renderedLine.length > 0){ //We found a line
                   currentPre.innerHTML = renderedLine.join('\n');
                }else{ //We found nothing - so show the original?
                   currentPre.innerHTML = preLine.join('\n');
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <form autocomplete="off" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="textFilter(this)" placeholder="filter">
    </form>
</header>
<div class="container context">
    <pre>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
        sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem 
        sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est
        qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet
        consectetur
        z
        adipisci velit
        sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et 
        dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima 
        veniam
    </pre>
</div>
```

It should work now, maybe context has more than 1 pre, then we need to do a bit extra

Comment: I couldnt get this to work yet, but let me fiddle with it a bit.

Comment: Will the `script` and `form` always be in the `head`? I moved it from there because it was very illogical to have it there, especially the `form`

Comment: Yes, the script and the form stays in the head. The form is actually part of a navbar, but i minified my code for stackoverflow

Comment: oof.. Are you sure it isn't `header`? The `head` is only used for setup like scripts and css, all rendered stuff should be in the `body`

Comment: oops. Yes, i meant `header`. haha.

Comment: Okay i'll make a finished solution now